# How to dynamically add the valueOptions of a singleSelect column in Material-UI's DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

This is my second question in SO, so apologize for any error in asking and formatting my question. I've been trying to accomplish what the tile said. Basically I have the following example of an array that I use to define my columns:

```
[
{
    field: 'name',
    headerName: 'Name',
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
},
{
    field: 'address',
    headerName: "Address",
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
},
{
    field: 'country',
    headerName: "Country",
    flex: 1,
    editable: true,
    type: 'singleSelect',
    valueOptions: 
    [
        // This should be dynamic
    ]
},
]
```

This is exported from a separate file, which is then imported in the React component that uses the DataGrid with these columns definitions.

The options are fetched from my REST API when a user logs in and they will be different for each user.

Is there anyway I could assign the `valueOptions` for the column `country` dynamically after the initial definitions?

Thank you!

P.S: I'm using the free version of Material-UI's DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

you can do by valueOptions field

const types = { // get value from services }

```
{
  field: 'country', width: 180,
  headerName: 'Country',
  type: 'singleSelect',
  editable: true,
  valueOptions: ({ row }) => { const options = [];
    types?.map((type) =>options.push(type.name))
    return options
  }

},
```

Comment: Using a method with the `row` argument instead of a direct array value for `valueOptions` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: how do I pass label and value using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the value of the "valueOptions" field after you have the answer of your REST service:

```js
fetch("your endpoint").then(answer => {
  columnsConfig.filter(column => column.field === "country").valueOptions = answer;
})
```

PS: you may have to transform the answer before setting the value of valueOptions

Answer (score 0):

valueOpt accepts a function that you can use to dynamically reference the values you are looking for.

Relevant issue:
https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3528

```
[{
    field: 'country',
    headerName: "Country",
    flex: 1,
    editable: true,
    type: 'singleSelect',
    valueOptions: ({id, row, field}) => {
        //return valueOptions for the row here
    }
}]
```