# How to implement searchable/filterable singleSelect column in MUI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I'm on day 3 of working this out and I'm just going in circles at this point. Basically, I have two API sources (json files) that I'm fetching in useEffect and storing them in an array. It's a big, changing list of products and "metadata" in key/value pairs.

This column "country" in the docs is exactly what I'm trying to implement https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/

A big problem I could be having is not knowing TypeScript at all, but here is my code so far.

Main Page

```
import {React, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import CircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Circle';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import { DataGrid, useGridApiRef, GridToolbar, gridStringOrNumberComparator } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import $ from 'jquery'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Skeleton from '@mui/material/Skeleton';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Scraper from './Scraper';
import { randomCountry, renderCountry, renderEditCountry } from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';


// Searchable field code
// https://github.com/mui/mui-x/tree/master/packages/grid/x-data-grid-generator/src

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649453/how-to-dynamically-add-the-valueoptions-of-a-singleselect-column-in-material-ui  


export default function EditQuote() {

  const location = useLocation()
  const id = location.pathname.split('quotes/')[1]
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
  
    const columns = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 20 },
        {
          field: 'country',
          headerName: 'Country',
          type: 'singleSelect',
          valueOptions: [],
          valueFormatter: ({ value }) => value?.label,
          generateData: randomCountry,
          renderCell: renderCountry,
          renderEditCell: renderEditCountry,
          sortComparator: (v1, v2, param1, param2) =>
            gridStringOrNumberComparator(v1.label, v2.label, param1, param2),
          width: 150,
          editable: true,
        },
        {
            field: 'model',
            headerName: 'Model',
            editable: true,
            flex: .5,
            minWidth: 100
          },
        { field: 'description', headerName: 'Description', editable: true, flex: 1, },
        {
          field: 'stock',
          headerName: 'Stock',
          editable: false,
          flex: .1,
          renderCell: (cellValues) => {
            if (cellValues.row.stock) {
              return (<CircleIcon sx={{color: '#8ced9c'}}/>)
            } else if (cellValues.row.stock === false){
              return (<CircleIcon sx={{color: '#ed8c8c'}}/>)
            } else {
              return
            }
          }
        },
        { field: 'quantity', headerName: 'Quantity', editable: true, type: 'number', flex: .25, },
        {
          field: 'price',
          headerName: 'Price',
          type: 'number',
          editable: true,
          flex: .25,
          valueGetter: (params) => {
            if (!params.value) {
              return '';
            }
            // Convert the decimal value to a percentage
            return `$${params.value}`;
          },
        },
        {
          field: 'markup',
          headerName: 'Markup',
          type: "singleSelect",
          valueOptions: [true, false],
          editable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'total',
          headerName: 'Total',
          type: 'number',
          editable: false,
          flex: .25,
          valueGetter: (cellValues) => {
            //console.log('total', cellValues)
            return cellValues;
          },
        },
        {
            field: "Delete",
            headerName: ' ',
            renderCell: (cellValues) => {
              return (
                <Button
                  onClick={(event) => {
                    handleDel(event, cellValues);
                  }}
                >
                  X
                </Button>
              );
            }
          }
      ];

      
      
      var rows = [
      ];
    
      const handleAddRow = () => {
        var rows = apiRef.current.getRowsCount()
        apiRef.current.updateRows([{id: rows + 1, title: 'new item'}]);
      };

      const handleDel = (event, cellValues) => {
        console.log(cellValues)
        apiRef.current.updateRows([{ id: cellValues.id, _action: 'delete' }])
      };

      const Save = async () => {
        $('#status').text('Saving...')
        var rows = apiRef.current.getRowsCount()
        var json = []
        for (let r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
            json.push(apiRef.current.getRow(r))
        }
        
        console.log(json)

        var res = await fetch('https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/64cb95d5b89b1e2299ca9847', {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                "X-Master-Key": sessionStorage.getItem("master"),
                "X-Access-Key": sessionStorage.getItem("key"),
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(json)

        })

        if (res.ok) {
          $('#status').text('Saved')
        } else {
            $('#status').text('Error')
        }

        console.log(res)
      }

      async function cellUpdate(updatedRow) {
        console.log(updatedRow)
      }

      

      async function PullRows(id) {
        await GetProducts()
        var data = await fetch('https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/64cb95d5b89b1e2299ca9847', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "X-Master-Key": sessionStorage.getItem("master"),
                "X-Access-Key": sessionStorage.getItem("key"),
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        var response = await data.json()
        var allQuotes = response.record
        for (let quote of allQuotes) {
          if (parseInt(id) === parseInt(quote.id)) {
            var currQuote = quote
            
          }
        }

        $('#jobname').text(currQuote.jobname)
        $('#customer').text(currQuote.customer)
        $('#description').text(currQuote.description)
        $('h1').text(`Editing Quote #${id}`)

        if (!currQuote.products) {currQuote.products = [{id: 1, item: 'No Products'}]}

        try {
          apiRef.current.updateRows(currQuote.products)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('quote products', currQuote.products)
          console.log(error)
        }
        
      }

      var allProducts = []

      async function GetProducts() {

        // Internal Products
        var dataInternal = await fetch('https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/64cb00dd8e4aa6225ec9acef/latest', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "X-Master-Key": sessionStorage.getItem("master"),
                "X-Access-Key": sessionStorage.getItem("key"),
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        var responseInternal = await dataInternal.json()
        var internalProducts = responseInternal.record
        try {
            for (let row of internalProducts) {
                allProducts.push({title: row.title, model: row.model})
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }

        // UI Products

        var uiProducts = await Scraper() 

        for (let ui of uiProducts.products) {
          ui.item = ui.title
          allProducts.push({title: ui.title, model: ui.model})
        }

        apiRef.current.updateColumns([{field: 'title', valueOptions: allProducts}])
        console.log('all products', allProducts)
        return allProducts

      }

      useEffect(() => {
        PullRows(id)
      })

      

      
    return (
      <Box sx={{ height: 'auto', width: '88vw' }}>
        <Button href="/quotes">
          Back to Quotes
        </Button>
        <h1>Editing Quote</h1>
        <br></br>
        <Divider></Divider>
        <br></br>
        <h2 id="jobname"> </h2>
        <h4 id="customer"> </h4>
        <p id="description"> </p>
        <DataGrid
            apiRef={apiRef}
            rowRe
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            autoHeight
            disableRowSelectionOnClick
            components={{
                NoRowsOverlay: () => (
                    <Box sx={{ height: 'auto', width: '88vw', padding: '30px' }}>
                        <Stack height="auto" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
                            Loading from database...
                        </Stack>  
                        <Typography variant="h4"><Skeleton /></Typography>          
                    </Box>
                  
                ),
                toolbar: GridToolbar 
            }}
            processRowUpdate={(updatedRow, originalRow) => { cellUpdate(updatedRow); } }
        />
        <Button size="small" onClick={handleAddRow}>
          Add a row
        </Button>
        <br></br>
        <a href="#?" type="button" id="save" onClick={Save}  className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</a>
        <p id="status"></p>
      </Box>
    );
  }
```

I'm trying to use `apiRef.current.updateColumns()` to change the valueOptions. Ultimatelty what I'm aiming to do is select a product from the dropdown and populate the information I have in the backend (price, model, description, instock) into the other columns in the row. I don't even need to render the cells I just need plain text and need to be able to search it like in the example. I was able to nearly replicate the example in my own app, but the dropdown would never close either. I think if I can get the data loaded into the dropdown and figure out the filtering inline (or whatever) I can take it from there.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. I've come close but just can't seem to figure out the last piece.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state in order to update the rows and columns of the data grid. Really, to update anything in React.

Change `const columns = [...all your columns...]` in your code to:

```js
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([...all your columns...])
```

And then change `apiRef.current.updateColumns([{field: 'title', valueOptions: allProducts}])` to:

```js
setColumns([{field: 'title', valueOptions: allProducts}])
```

After that, it should be working. Typically you won't need to use data grid's `apiRef`, this is for complex use cases that need to hook into the inner workings of the component. You should also change `rows` to use this pattern.

Here's a good article to help understand the vital concept of state in React: https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Working on the same issue and also had to dig deep to find where they specify stuff to execute on this.

Everything you need to render the same autocomplete as in 'country' column is in this file in the mui repo:

```
https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/next/packages/grid/x-data-grid-generator/src/renderer/renderEditCountry.tsx
```

You just need to create a similar components based on autocomplete (look at imports at the top of that file) and then in your grid definition specify that components as 'editRenderCell: '

For example, my non-TS version looks like this (complete rip of their example from url above)

Autocomplete component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useGridApiContext } from "@mui/x-data-grid-premium";
import Autocomplete, { autocompleteClasses } from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/styles";

export default function EditAutocomplete({ params, renderOptions }) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const { id, value, field } = params;

  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    (event, newValue) => {
      apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({ id, field, value: newValue }, event);

    },
    [apiRef, field, id]
  );

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      sx={{
        height: "100%",
        [`& .${autocompleteClasses.inputRoot}`]: {
          ...theme.typography.body2,
          padding: "1px 0",
          height: "100%",
          "& input": {
            padding: "0 16px",
            height: "100%",
          },
        },
      }}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={renderOptions}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
      autoHighlight
      fullWidth
      open
      disableClearable
      renderOption={(optionProps, option) => (
        <Box
          component="li"
          sx={{
            "& > img": {
              mr: 1.5,
              flexShrink: 0,
            },
          }}
          {...optionProps}
        >
          {option}
        </Box>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <InputBase
          autoFocus
          fullWidth
          id={params.id}
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            autoComplete: "new-password", // disable autocomplete and autofill
          }}
          {...params.InputProps}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

... and then importing it where my datagrid is and adding it as renderEditCell prop:

```
import EditAutocomplete from "components/AdminTable/components/EditAutocomplete";
...

const columns = [
...
{
      field: "countries",
      headerName: "Countries",
      type: "singleSelect",
      width: 80,
      editable: true,
      valueOptions: countriesOptions,
      renderEditCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <EditAutocomplete params={params} renderOptions={countriesOptions} />
        );
      },
    },
...
]
```